# sendmail configuration to stop local delivery

Tags: centos, smtp, sendmail

I have configured sendmail in my CentOs 6.4. Using current configuration I can send mail but problem is with address like @domain.com.

My scenario is like this.
Server 1: xyz.com  (contain http, domain panel also point this) 
Server 2: test.xyz.com (contain sendmail configuration)

this xyz.com is assigned in domain panel and A record is created for test.xyz.com. Now as I have configured sendmail in Server 2, It can deliver all mail outside but when I use address like user@xyz.com it's deliver that mail locally. Actually I have setup google mail server for address like @xyz.com and required MX records are added for same.

I want to deliver all mail from server 2 to my google server. Please help me to solve this. I am grateful to you for same.

My sendmail.mc is,

```
divert(-1)dnl
include(`/usr/share/sendmail-cf/m4/cf.m4')dnl
VERSIONID(`setup for linux')dnl
OSTYPE(`linux')dnl
define(`SMART_HOST', `mailout.serverpronto.com')dnl
define(`confDEF_USER_ID', ``8:12'')dnl
define(`confTO_CONNECT', `1m')dnl
define(`confTRY_NULL_MX_LIST', `True')dnl
define(`confDONT_PROBE_INTERFACES', `True')dnl
define(`PROCMAIL_MAILER_PATH', `/usr/bin/procmail')dnl
define(`ALIAS_FILE', `/etc/aliases')dnl
define(`STATUS_FILE', `/var/log/mail/statistics')dnl
define(`UUCP_MAILER_MAX', `2000000')dnl
define(`confUSERDB_SPEC', `/etc/mail/userdb.db')dnl
define(`confPRIVACY_FLAGS', `authwarnings,novrfy,noexpn,restrictqrun')dnl
define(`confAUTH_OPTIONS', `A')dnl
define(`confTO_IDENT', `0')dnl
FEATURE(`no_default_msa', `dnl')dnl
FEATURE(`smrsh', `/usr/sbin/smrsh')dnl
FEATURE(`mailertable', `hash -o /etc/mail/mailertable.db')dnl
FEATURE(`virtusertable', `hash -o /etc/mail/virtusertable.db')dnl
FEATURE(redirect)dnl
FEATURE(always_add_domain)dnl
FEATURE(use_cw_file)dnl
FEATURE(use_ct_file)dnl
FEATURE(local_procmail, `', `procmail -t -Y -a $h -d $u')dnl
FEATURE(`access_db', `hash -T<TMPF> -o /etc/mail/access.db')dnl
FEATURE(`blacklist_recipients')dnl
EXPOSED_USER(`root')dnl
DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Port=smtp, Name=MTA')dnl
FEATURE(`accept_unresolvable_domains')dnl
MASQUERADE_AS(`xyz.com')dnl
FEATURE(masquerade_envelope)dnl
FEATURE(masquerade_entire_domain)dnl
MASQUERADE_DOMAIN(xyz.com)dnl
MAILER(smtp)dnl
MAILER(procmail)dnl
define(`MAIL_HUB', `xyz.com')dnl
define(`LOCAL_RELAY', `xyz.com.')dnl
```

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/536051/how-do-i-configure-sendmail-to-send-mail-via-mx-record-and-not-to-localhost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, your server will point to some domain name so it's always the issue that when you send any mail to address with @domain.com, it deliver it locally.

1. You can get my sendmail.mc from [here](http://pastebin.com/U4nUPGu0).
2. vim /etc/mail/sendmail.mc and copy paste it
3. Replace your domain in place of "domain.com" everywhere and put your SMART HOST server address in place of "host.domain.com"
4. echo '$=w' | sendmail -bt
5. Check here your domain (i.e. domain.com or mail id user.domain.com) is not in entry. It deliver mail to local client for which host shows here. So if domain.com shows here than all @domain.com will deliver locally.
6. To change hostname, check /etc/hosts/ (change if domain.com only is there. it should be mail.domain.com or any whatever mail server name or hostname you mention)
7. Check /etc/mail/local-host-names (Empty if any entry), check /etc/sysconfig/network (hostname should not domain.com)
8. Type "hostname" and you should get mail.domain.com or other but not domain.com. If so than type "hostname mail.domain.com"
9. /etc/init.d/network restart
10. sudo make -C /etc/mail
11. service sendmail restart
12. Confirm again the local delivery list, echo '$=w' | sendmail -bt

Answer (score 0):

I spent a lot of time on this, but these two lines did it for me in the end. Can it be that you have dot (.) in your LOCAL_RELAY argument?

```
define(`MAIL_HUB', `xyz.com')dnl
define(`LOCAL_RELAY', `xyz.com')dnl
```

Update.
So it seems that you properly have to masquerade your domain.

[Reference](https://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/docs/m4/masquerading.html)

I think this means that you should have:

```
MASQUERADE_AS(`xyz.com')
```

and

```
MASQUERADE_DOMAIN(`test.xyz.com')
```

Play around a little with all these options and see what happens.

Comment: Hi Gustaf! Thanks. I have check in both scenario with (.) and without also but in both same problem. Actually main headache is that, In my scenario there are two servers comes in pictures.